# How to save list / list items into csv via CSOM/ cross-domain?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have searched that most answers are using powershell.

Comment: You should add the question and problem in the body too, rather than having it only in Title.

Answer (score 2):

*No built in feature for this*. You can try it regular C# way. I mean [how to create csv using C#](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=how%20to%20create%20csv%20using%20C%23&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enBD645BD645&oq=how%20to%20create%20csv%20using%20C%23&aqs=chrome..69i57.647j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22850309/1294606) is regarding object array to csv.

Now try to convert it for SharePoint list to csv.

```
var myListItems = oWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle("myListItems").GetItems(new CamlQuery());
 var csvLines = myListItems.Select(item => new object[] {
     item["FirstName"].ToString(),
         item["LastName"].ToString(),
         //Other columns
 }).ToList();

 var csvData = new StringBuilder();

 csvLines.ForEach(line => {
     csvData.AppendLine(string.Join(",", line));
 });

 System.IO.File.WriteAllText("File Path", csvData.ToString());
```